# Correct use of async/await in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous

The following code won't compile with the error: `Value of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of System.Data.DataTable)' cannot be converted to 'System.Data.DataTable`

```
Private m_country_dt As DataTable = getCountriesAsync()


Private Async Function getCountriesAsync() As Task(Of DataTable)
    Dim dt As DataTable = Await Task(Of DataTable).Factory.StartNew(Function() getCountries_dt())

    Return dt
End Function

Private Function getCountries_dt() As DataTable
    Dim sp As New dbCore.StoredProcedure
    Return sp.GetAllCountries()
End Function
```

Can someone tell me what I might be doing wrong here? `GetAllCountries` is a function that queries a SQL database for.. all the countries in it and returns this in a `DataTable`. This code is located inside of a Module.

Comment: Is there a reason Visual Studio is auto-correcting the return type of getCountriesAsync to `Task(Of DataTable)`?

Comment: `Async` methods must return `Task` or `Task(Of T)` (or, if you absolutely must, `void`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `Await` it to unwrap the `Task (Of DataTable)`.

On a side note, you should [prefer `Task.Run` over `Task.Factory.StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) (I describe why on my blog). Though in this case, I would try to use the ADO.NET async methods instead of just running the synchronous methods on a background task.